# Transition background image width but maintain height

Tags: html, css

First here is the picture

[image]

The picture is 200px long and 50px height. And if i hover over the image the width should be changed to 300px with a transition effect. At the moment if i hover the image scale the height & width new, not only the width. How can i change it?

Here a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fpr7ku62/) + code

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.eins{
    background-image: url(http://img3.fotos-hochladen.net/thumbnail/einse402yr1bzf_thumb.jpg);
    background-size: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

.eins:hover{
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link href='index.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


    </head>
    
    <body>
        
        <div class="eins">
        </div>
    
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's worth noting that you'd have better results in this particular case by using a red background and a red triangle image on the right side. This would eliminate distortion artifacts.

Comment: Yeha but i dont know how to use it... I create fix a triangle give me a secound

Comment: Here is the [image](http://img3.fotos-hochladen.net/thumbnail/imageeev8lqsjemta_thumb.jpg) Maybe you can help me

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/oo1eb14c

Comment: @isherwood Thanks! Thats really nice! Thanks man.

Comment: Sure. If you google a bit you'll find ways to do it with CSS alone.

Comment: Yeha i found something, but its way to hard for me. And i dont know how to use it correctly^^ But its fine with the image.

Comment: @Skeptar - In case you change your mind. ----> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o51mdxog/2/). :)

Comment: @chipChocolate.py can i give the arrow a border of 1px in black?

Comment: @Skeptar - Sure. give me a few minutes.

Comment: @Skeptar - Here you go ----> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o51mdxog/5/). I've used `svg` for the triangle this time since it makes the border more consistent across all browsers. Here is a CSS only solution. ----> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o51mdxog/3/), choose which ever you like.

Comment: Thanks! :) Thats really nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `background-size: 100% 100%` not `background-size: 100%`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.eins {
  background-image: url(http://img3.fotos-hochladen.net/thumbnail/einse402yr1bzf_thumb.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.eins:hover {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link href='index.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="eins">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you help me again? :D "isherwood" wrote -> It's worth noting that you'd have better results in this particular case by using a red background and a red triangle image on the right side. This would eliminate distortion artifacts <- Now i created the [image](http://img3.fotos-hochladen.net/thumbnail/imageeev8lqsjemta_thumb.jpg), but i dont know how to use it correct.

Comment: @Skeptar - Yes, what do you need help with?

Comment: isherwood gave me an jsfiddle :/ I should wait next time. Sorry! But thanks for you help!

Comment: @chipChocholate.py Okay thanks thats amazing too! Now i have to read again something about the pseudo-element :after, because i dont know the task about it :) But thanks man !

Comment: @Skeptar - I'll give you another Fiddle without any image, using CSS alone. :)

Comment: you dont have to, really. Its fine like this :) The problem, my brain wont understand it only with css... I found [this](http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/lotjh). Its really usefull, but i dont know how to use the triangle then...